# If speed of light is constant for all inertial frames would a photon take longer to go between the ends in a moving cart, than it was at rest?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames

if a photon was sent from one end of a moving trolly to the other end would the photon travel more distance than the length of the trolly

Comment: it would just travel the distance of the trolley, but seen from outside, it would travel a different distance. Is this your question? but the length of the trolley is different from the length of a not moving trolley.

Comment: @trula, I tried to figure out in the perception of the observer at the other corner of the trolly. would he find it takes longer for the photon to reach him than it was at rest?

Answer (score 3):

All inertial reference frames are indistinguishable - there is no possible experiment you can do that will tell you whether you're at rest or moving at a constant speed. A person inside a trolley moving at a constant speed can't tell whether that speed is zero (at rest) or non-zero (moving). The person will not measure anything different when the trolley is moving at a constant speed versus not moving at all, as that would allow them to distinguish between inertial reference frames, which is impossible. The person always just sees the photon cover the distance across the trolley.

Comment: thanks that makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't take the same time.

Once you decide that the speed of light is constant in all reference frames, then you have to fudge time and distance to be different in different frames, to let that be true. And when you fudge them just the right amounts, you get the right answers.

When I say "fudge factor" it sounds pejorative, like there's something wrong with doing that. But it does get the right answer, and if you assume that times and distances are the same for everybody then you get wrong answers. So there's nothing wrong with it.

If you try to get an intuitive sense of what it all means, for that the important thing is to find something that feels good to you. Some way to think about it that doesn't contradict the math. Every interpretation that does fit the math is OK.

Answer (score 1):

> if a photon was sent from one end of a moving trolly [sic] to the other end would the photon travel more distance than the length of the trolly [sic]

An observer sitting in the trolley (at rest with respect to the trolley) sees the photon travel a distance $\Delta x_T$ equal to the length of the trolley ($L$) in a time $\Delta t_T=L/c$.

An observer sitting on the lawn watching the trolley roll by sees the photon travel a distance equal to
$$
\Delta x_L = L\times\left(\frac{1+\frac{v}{c}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}\right)\approx L + v\times\frac{L}{c}\;,
$$
where the expression on the far right-hand side is what would be expected based on non-relativistic calculations.

And the observer sitting on the lawn watching the trolley roll by sees the photon travel this distance in a time equal to
$$
\Delta t_L = \frac{L}{c}\times\left(\frac{1+\frac{v}{c}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}\right)\approx \frac{L}{c} + v\times\frac{L}{c^2}\;.
$$

---

In either case, we see that the speed of light is:
$$
c = \frac{L}{L/c} = \frac{L\times\left(\frac{1+\frac{v}{c}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}\right)}{\frac{L}{c}\times\left(\frac{1+\frac{v}{c}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}\right)}\;.
$$

This constancy of the speed of light is built into the equations of transformation from one frame to the other, namely:
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}ct_L \\ x_L\end{matrix}\right)
=
\left(\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}} & \frac{v/c}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}} \\ \frac{v/x}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}\end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}ct_T \\ x_T\end{matrix}\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

This is really a "Do the Lorentz Transform" situation, since it is once of the easiest. In the trolly's frame ($S$), there are two events (labeled by $(ct, x)\rightarrow (t, x)$, with $c=1$):

Transmission:

$$ T= (0, 0) $$

at one end, and Receiving at the other:

$$ R = (L, L)$$

for a total time of:

$$ t = L $$

Pretty basic.

Now transform to a moving ($\beta = v/c$) frame $S'$:

$$ T = (0, 0)' $$

$$ R = \big(\gamma(t-\beta x), \gamma(x-\beta t)\big)' $$
$$ R = \big(\gamma L (1-\beta), \gamma L (1-\beta) \big)' $$

for a time difference of:

$$ t'=\gamma L (1-\beta) $$

so you pick up a correction for the motion of  the Rx end, $(1-\beta)$, and one for time dilation, $\gamma$.

Note: for $v\ll c$, the motion correction is 1st order, and the relativistic correction is 2nd order.

Answer (score 0):

In the frame of the trolley, the light moves from one end of the trolley to the other, so it covers a distance equal to the length of the trolley.

In any other frame in which the trolley is moving lengthways, the light moves a different distance- either a longer or shorter distance, depending on the direction of the trolley's movement relative to the movement of the light. If the trolley is  moving in the same direction as the light, then the light will travel a longer distance. If the trolley is moving in the opposite direction to the light, then the light will travel a shorter distance.

You should see, therefore, that the time taken for the light to complete its journey in the frame of the ground will be either greater than or less than the time it takes to complete its journey in the frame of the trolley, depending upon the direction in which the trolley is moving.

Answer (score 0):

If the photon is traveling in the same direction as the trolley  it travels farther than the length of the trolley.  If it is traveling in the opposite direction, it travels less far than the length of the trolley.

This is true in any frame where the trolley is moving, and has nothing to do with relativity unless you want to compare the distances traveled in different frames, which you have not asked about.